# Faithfull representation of $\mathfrak h \rtimes V$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $\mathfrak h \subset \mathfrak {gl} (V)$ a Lie Algebra. Consider the semidirect product $\mathfrak h \rtimes V$ 
$$[(H_1,v_1),(H_2,v_2)] = ([H_1,H_2], H_1 v_2 - H_2 v_1). $$

I'm stuck in this question

> **Question:** Let $\mathfrak{h} \subset \mathfrak {gl} (V)$ a Lie Algebra of linear transformations and consider the semidirect product $ \mathfrak g = \mathfrak h \rtimes V $. Find a faithful representation of $\mathfrak h \rtimes V$.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional at least?  (I asked just in case.  I don't have a solution even for finite dimensional $V$ yet.)

Comment: I do think so. I will edit my question.

Comment: If $V$ is finite dim, then Ado's theorem guarantees that a finite dim faithful representation exists.  I just don't know how to construct it.  The easy case is when $\bigcap_{H\in\mathfrak{h}} \ker H=\{0\}$.  Then, the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{h} \rtimes V$ has trivial center, and therefore the adjoint representation is faithful.

Comment: Yes. This kind of statement always confuses me, I think that "find" means "explicit construct". But I agree with you that Ado's theorem guarantees that this representation exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An explicit representation is given by $\rho:\mathfrak{g}\to \mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb R\times V)$,
$$\rho(H,v)=\begin{pmatrix}0 &0_{1\times n} \\ 0_{n\times 1} & H\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0 &0_{1\times n} \\ v & 0_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix}.$$
(here I think on $V$ as $\mathbb{R}^n$, and use matrices).
The verification is straightforward.

More important then this is how to get there. Suppose $H$ is a Lie subgroup of $GL(V)$ that integrates $\mathfrak{h}$. If you think on the natural semidirect product of the groups $H$ and $V$,  $H\rtimes V$, then $H\rtimes V$ acts on $V$ by combining multiplication and translation:
$$(h,v)x=hx+v.$$
You can even define the semidirect product through this action. This action, however, is not linear. You can fix this situation by considering a slightly extended action on $V\times \mathbb{R}$:
$$ (h,v)(x,\alpha)=hx+\alpha v.$$
(note that the last action imitates the first one when you restrict to $\{1\}\times V$.) The last action (magically) happens to be linear. Taking $V=\mathbb{R}^n$, its explicit representation is
$$\tilde\rho(h,v)=\begin{pmatrix}1 &0_{1\times n} \\ v & 0_{n\times n}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 &0_{1\times n} \\ 0_{n\times 1} & h\end{pmatrix}.$$
You just need to differentiate $\tilde \rho$.

Comment: I think your construction works over any base field $\mathbb{F}$ even when $V$ is infinite dim.  Define the $(\mathfrak{h}\rtimes V)$-action on $\mathbb{F}\times V$ by $(H,v)\cdot (t,w)=(0,tv+Hw)$ for any $(H,v)\in \mathfrak{h}\rtimes V$ and for any $(t,w) \in \mathbb{F}\times V$.  Therefore, there is no need to assume that $V$ is finite dim at all.

Comment: Nice approach thx!